# Switching from Lubuntu to Mac: how do I import existing virtual machines?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, migration

On Lubuntu 13.10 I had some virtual machines running in VirtualBox 4.2.26.
While backing up, all I ever did was make a copy of VirtualBox VMs folder.

I have now switched to OSX, and now I am curious, can I simply import the VMs through "Import Appliance" under File Menu?

[This article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26217_01/E26796/html/qs-import-vm.html) says that I first needed to have exported it to the ovf or ova file format.

Now that my Lubuntu system is gone, is there another workaround?

If not, could I make another VM and mount the existing virtual hard drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Import Appliance" option is just for VMs that have been previously exported to the Open Virtualization Format through the "Export Appliance" option. Your VMs can be imported easily, just copy them out of your backup into the new VirtualBox VMs folder and then go in and manually open the VMNAME.vbox file in each VM folder to import them.

Comment: exactly what you said solved my problem.